# MapInfo cannot join after deleted some rows with "del"

Tags: mapinfo

I tried to join my table with another one, with the update column. But it gives me an error, that it cannot be updated. Actually it does update the table to a certain point.

I deleted some rows before I tried to update the table, manually by clickling left on the row and pressed the key "del", so the object got removed, the row still kinda exist, but only in grey. But that is the point where the join stops, from there on there are no further entries.

I tried to close and reopen the table, but the grey rows are still in there, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to PACK your tables after deleting rows.

Table/Maintenance/Pack table...